# jQuery Validation add valid class to another element

Tags: jquery, class, jquery-validate

Is there any equivalent of the errorPlacement for the validPlacement in [jQueryValidation](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/)?

My goal is to add the valid class to another element.

Thanks.

Comment: You can use "success" option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved the problem using success option.

```
var validatorOptions = {    
    success: function(label) {
        var element = '#' + label.attr('for');
        $(element).addClass('myClass');
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write a custom validation function.  A custom validation function takes 2 arguments: value and element

That gives you access to the element parameter.